# Copying an object from one NSDictionary to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

What's the cleanest way to copy an object from one NSDictionary to another? I have to extract specific values from a dictionary and store them in a new dictionary. Currently I have some simple code like so...

```
NSString *value1 = [dictA objectForKey:@"1"];
[dictB setObject:value1 forKey:@"1"];
```

...but it feels like it has more common code than I'd like.  I have to do this many times and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern Objective-C syntax you could actually write `dictA[@"key1"] = dictB[@"key1"]` with mutable dictionaries.

Comment: Good answer, I always forgot to use shortcut...+1

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this for a lot of keys, consider using `+ (id)dictionaryWithSharedKeySet:(id)keyset`. You'll have to create the keyset first with `sharedKeySetForKeys:`
This would lead to only two lines of code...

Comment: Thanks, SAE, this is interesting. I'm looking at the documentation, but it's not clear to me how I can use the sharedKeySet to create a new NSDictionary object. Would you mind posting some example code if you get a chance?

Answer (score 1):

Why not in just a single line?

```
[dictB setObject:[dictA objectForKey:@"1"] forKey:@"1"];
```

In the above code, you can change the key if you want.

Comment: The -1 wasn't mine, I actually upvoted you for your help, but I don't want to use a single line because my actual variable names are much more verbose and that makes it difficult to maintain an 80 char line cap.  Also, in my opinion, that has the same amount of common code as my original approach.

Comment: 2nd what? Copying the entire dictionary?  I don't need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys are the same between the two dictionaries, then maybe you can make a helper method like this:

```
- (void)copyObjectFromDictA:(NSDictionary *)dictA toDictB:(NSDictionary *)dictB forKeys:(NSArray *)keys
{
  for (NSString *key in keys) 
  {
    [dictB setObject:[dictA objectForKey:key] forKey:key]];
  }
}
```

Comment: use NSMutableDictionary and you have an ] to much:
the correct version should be:


- (void)copyObjectFromDictA:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictA toDictB:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictB forKeys:(NSArray *)keys
{
    for (NSString *key in keys)
    {
        [dictB setObject:[dictA objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}